# Erro ao instalar mongo-hack no Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

Ao instalar o o mongo-hack no Ubuntu está sendo gerado o seguinte erro:

> npm install -g mongo-hacker
>   |
>   mongo-hacker@0.0.12 install
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/mongo-hacker make install
>
> cat config.js base.js hacks/aggregation.js hacks/api.js
>
> hacks/auto_complete.js hacks/cmd_search.js hacks/color.js
>   hacks/common.js  hacks/count.js hacks/dbref.js
>   hacks/find_and_modify.js hacks/helpers.js  hacks/index_paranoia.js
>   hacks/old_aggregation.js hacks/prompt.js  hacks/show.js
>   hacks/sh_status.js hacks/uuid.js hacks/verbose.js >  mongo_hacker.js
>
> INSTALLATION
>
> Linking MongoHacker to .mongorc.js in your home directory: ln -sf
>   "/usr/lib/node_modules/mongo-hacker/mongo_hacker.js" ~/.mongorc.js ln:
>   failed to access ‘/root/.mongorc.js’: Permission denied make: ***
>   [install] Error 1
>
> npm ERR! mongo-hacker@0.0.12 install: make install
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the mongo-hacker@0.0.12 install script.
>
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mongo-hacker package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     make install
>
> npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls mongo-hacker
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! System Linux 3.19.0-47-generic
>
> npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g"
>   "mongo-hacker"
>
> npm ERR! cwd /mongo-hacker/mongo-hacker/hacks
>
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
>
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> mongo-hacker@0.0.12 postuninstall /usr/lib/node_modules/mongo-hacker
>   make uninstall
>
> rm -f ~/.mongorc.js rm: cannot remove ‘/root/.mongorc.js’: Permission
>   denied
>
> make: *** [uninstall] Error 1
>
> npm WARN continuing anyway mongo-hacker@0.0.12 postuninstall: make
>   uninstall
>
> npm WARN continuing anyway Exit status 2
>
> npm ERR! not ok code 0

Já tentei como root e mesmo assim o erro continua.

Answer (score 1):

Passei pelo mesmo problema hoje.

Depois de tentar várias soluções, encontrei essa com a qual eu consegui resolver esse problema.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

Se quiser consultar o link original :  https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions